# Is atomic_fetch_add_explicit atomic within threadgroup memory?

Tags: ios, atomic, metal, threadgroup

The following code snippet in a Metal compute kernel suggests that `atomic_fetch_add_explicit` does not have an atomic read-modify-write within threadgroup memory.

The value of `i` is not unique within the threadgroup as I expect it to be.

Am I using it wrong??

```
threadgroup atomic_int index;  
atomic_store_explicit( &index, 0, memory_order_relaxed );  
threadgroup_barrier( mem_flags::mem_none );  
int i = atomic_fetch_add_explicit( &index, 1, memory_order_relaxed );
```

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed correct and functions atomically as expected.
The error was in my code verifying the uniqueness of `i`.